# Decide Id based on RANK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
id          || Account 
=======================
101         || A1
102         || A2
103         || A3
104         || A3
105         || A3
```

I want to write a select query that gives me the same id if the account is same. So, for all the Account A3 I want to have New Id as 103.

Expected result is

```
OldId       || Account || NewID
==================================
101         || A1      || 101
102         || A2      || 102
103         || A3      || 103     
104         || A3      || 103 
105         || A3      || 103
```

Comment: the lowest id for a account from your table becomes newid ? is that the rule ?

Comment: Yes, either lowest or the highest.

Comment: Cannot be lowest **OR** Highest ... you will have to pick one. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ID is the sequence

```
Declare @Table table (Id int,Account varchar(25))
Insert @Table values
(101,'A1'),
(102,'A2'),
(103,'A3'),
(104,'A3'),
(105,'A3')

Select OldID = ID
      ,Account
      ,NewID = min(ID) over (Partition By Account)
 From @Table
 Group by Account,ID
```

Return

```
OldID   Account NewID
101     A1      101
102     A2      102
103     A3      103
104     A3      103
105     A3      103
```

Comment: The last row should have id 103

Comment: I assumed the order was sequential based on the ID.  Clearly I did not understand the request

Comment: @John: You shouldn't need a `group by` in your query. Otherwise, this is a very good answer.

Comment: @sstan  Old habits die hard.  When I see min, I think group by

Answer (score 1):

try this ... let me know if you need any clarifications

In this case the ID doesnt have to be in a sequence.

```
select 
a.id as OldId,
a.account,
b.newID  as newID 
From 
accountstable a inner join 
(
select account, min(id) as NewID from accountstable -- Get the Min or Max id that will become the NewId
group by account
) b
on a.account = b.account
```

Answer (score 1):

borrow the table created by John Cappelletti, maybe you can also write sql like below:

Declare @Table table (Id int,Account varchar(25))
    Insert @Table
    values (101,'A1'), (102,'A2'), (103,'A3'), (104,'A3'), (105,'A3')

---

select *,rank()over(order by account)+100 as NewID 
from @table